# Getting error when trying to create a user after installing pundit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pundit

I get the following error whenever I try to create a new user after I installed pundit within my project. It seems as if it can't find pundit, even though I installed it and included the gem and ran bundle install.

```
app_1  | ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant ApplicationController::Pundit):
app_1  |   
app_1  | app/controllers/application_controller.rb:3:in `<class:ApplicationController>'
app_1  | app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app_1  | app/controllers/v1/users_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

My ApplicationController.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  include Pundit

  after_action :verify_authorized, except: :index, unless: :skip_pundit?
  after_action :verify_policy_scoped, only: :index, unless: :skip_pundit?

  private

  def skip_pundit?
    devise_controller? || params[:controller] =~ /(^(rails_)?admin)|(^pages$)/
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you restart rails server?

Comment: Yes, and it now gives me the following error: NoMethodError (undefined method `authenticate_user!' for #<V1::UsersController:0x0055dd04aad340>)

Comment: Are your devise routes namespaced somehow?

Comment: Yes, they are.                                                                                              
 `namespace :v1, defaults: { format: :json } do
    resources :sessions, only: [:create, :destroy]
    resources :artists do
      resources :requests
    end
    resources :users, only: [:create]
  end`

Comment: Try to use `authenticate_v1_user!`

Comment: Now it gives me: `NoMethodError (undefined method authenticate_v1_user!' for #<V1::UsersController:0x0055dd04fa7df0>)`

Answer (score 0):

Restarting rails server worked for me